# Generate URLs with React Router from slugs in a database

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, airtable

I have a React SPA that displays content from a database.

Every time a button is clicked, React queries the db, and changes the content without changing the URL.

I would like each time the button is clicked for React Router to change the URL to match a slug stored with each item in the db.

Is this possible?

Currently my routes file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home.js';
import Component1 from './Component1.js';

export default () =>
(<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/component1" component={Component1} exact />
  <Route path="/component1/:product" component={Component1} />
</Switch>);
```

This means that if I go to `www.url.com/component1/bananas`, I can pass the `prop` of `bananas` to the component `Component1` as `this.props.match.params.product`.

But this does not help me, I don't think.

I would like for `Component1`, reading from the db, to tell React Router what the slug should be.

It feels like the questions is related to URL parameters -- but I want to dynamically generate URLs rather than dynamically match URLs.

The React component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Airtable from "airtable";

const base = new Airtable({ apiKey: "API_KEY" }).base(
  "BASE_ID"
);

let i = 0;

export default class Component1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      content: '',
      records: '',
      slug: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getRecords()
  }

  getRecords = () => {
    base("BASE_NAME")
      .select({ view: "Grid view" })
      .eachPage((records, fetchNextPage) => {
        this.setState({ records }, () => this.parseRecord(i));
        fetchNextPage();
      });
  }

  parseRecord = i => {
    const product = this.state.records[i].fields;

    this.setState({
      content: product.Content
      slug: product.Slug
    });
  };

  onClickNext = () => {
    i < this.state.records.length - 2 ? i++ : (i = 0);
    this.parseRecord(i);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.content} onClick={onClickNext} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Please  indicate what slugs is? Also please share the code snippet where you are switching the product!

Comment: Slugs are SEO-friendly strings. Following the example above, if the slug in the db is "detailed-item-description" then the entire url should be "www.url.com/component1/detailed-item-description".

Comment: You want to change the content as you are doing now but change the url right? But then when you go to `www.url.com/component1/bananas` The bananas page will not be loaded.
`I can pass the prop of bananas to the component Component1 as this.props.match.params.product.But this does not help me, I don't think.`
Why doesn't this approach work for you? This is how routing is supposed to work. Visit a page and based on the url the content is loaded.
Also doing this will not help SEO as well, because when the crawler visits the url the content is not loaded. It will only switch content via click

Comment: True, the approach solves half of the problem. I think I am still left with the other half -- how to generate unique URLs from the content.

Comment: I assume that the url generation is done separately and assigned to product.Slug right? How is that related to the problem here?